# ruby-savon communicate with mono-wcf

Tags: ruby, wcf, mono, savon

i am new to mono wcf, and i came across some problems about my code.
 recent, i use ruby-savon to get data from wcf host on mono.

and this is my ruby code:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do 
wsdl.document="http://localhost:9000/MonoWcf/MonoSevice/wsdl" 
end
puts client.wsdl.soap_actions
response = client.request  :get_data
```

and this this puts :

```
ruby -KU -- '/home/charlot/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/rubyfun/soap/savon.rb'
W, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.845966 #10527]  WARN -- : HTTPI executes HTTP GET using the httpclient adapter
get_data
get_data_using_data_contract
D, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.856091 #10527] DEBUG -- : SOAP request: http://localhost:9000/MonoWcf/MonoSevice/soap
D, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.856294 #10527] DEBUG -- : SOAPAction: "http://localhost:9000/IMonoService/GetData", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 293
D, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.856329 #10527] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/"   xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Body><GetData>
</GetData>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
W, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.856403 #10527]  WARN -- : HTTPI executes HTTP POST using the httpclient adapter
D, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.873963 #10527] DEBUG -- : SOAP response (status 415):
D, [2012-12-21T02:45:41.874057 #10527] DEBUG -- : 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/soap/response.rb:108:in `raise_errors': Savon::HTTP::Error
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/soap/response.rb:18:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/soap/request.rb:35:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/soap/request.rb:35:in `response'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:86:in `request'
    from /home/charlot/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/rubyfun/soap/savon.rb:15:in `dosoap'
    from /home/charlot/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/rubyfun/soap/savon.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

**

### and this is the mono-wcf wsdl :

**
  `

```
<import location="http://localhost:9000/MonoWcf/MonoSevice/wsdl?wsdl=wsdl0" namespace="http://localhost:9000"/>
<types/>
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMonoService" type="i0:IMonoService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="GetData">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:9000/IMonoService/GetData" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetDataUsingDataContract">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:9000/IMonoService/GetDataUsingDataContract" style="document"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="service">
    <port name="BasicHttpBinding_IMonoService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IMonoService">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:9000/MonoWcf/MonoSevice/soap"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

`
  **but when i host wcf in windows(7), it really get the data.

my os is: ubuntu 12
mono version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  x86
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

really thanks your help!

Comment: Not an answer, but in these cases, using Wireshark to figure out exactly what's going over the wire, is often a good start.

Comment: The error message that I'm seeing with tcpdump is 'HTTP/1.1 415 Expected content-type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' but got 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'

Comment: So that's a bug in Mono's WCF stack.  Should be an easy fix, I'll have a look it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Mono's WCF code that I just fixed in [mono/master commit ea2f2cd](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ea2f2cde4286fa7af223e0c6e4950f85e42e8208).

Ruby-savon sends `Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8`, but the server expected `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`.  This is incorrect, the check is supposed to be case-insensitive and ignore whitespace.

You need to either compile the latest mono from github or, as a temporary workaround, somehow make ruby-savon send `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`.

**Temporary Workaround**

Edit `lib/savon/request.rb` (it's in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/savon-2.0.2` on my Mac), at the top, there's

```
CONTENT_TYPE = {
  1 => "text/xml;charset=%s",
  2 => "application/soap+xml;charset=%s"
}
```

Change that into

```
CONTENT_TYPE = {
  1 => "text/xml; charset=%s",
  2 => "application/soap+xml; charset=%s"
}
```

Then set the encoding to "utf-8", for instance:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(:wsdl => "http://localhost:9999/MyService?wsdl", :encoding => "utf-8")
puts client.operations
response = client.call(:hello)
```

Tested with Ruby 1.8.7 on my Mac.